# stop window.location.replace from decoding url string

Tags: javascript, url

I have a url that needs to be mapped to a specific format, where some slashes should remain as %20f. So for instance:

```
http://myUrl.com/section1/section2/section%2fnamewithslash/?somequery=1
```

Such a url should keep the %2f in the section name.  Unfortunately, I can't change this to remove the slash from the section name.

The issue is that when I call window.location.replace, it changes that %20f to a slash, which throws off the link.

You can see a fiddle example here https://jsfiddle.net/Kolichikov/k480rnff/
To see what I mean, follow the link, and right click on the results frame and click view frame source. You'll the see the url in the browser.

So my question is how do I replace the current resource with the one from the url without decoding the link?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: unfortunate thing to use in a url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an onclick event instead of processing the link in `href`.

```
<script>
  <a href="#" onclick="window.location.replace('http://myUrl.com/section1/section2/section%2fnamewithslash/?somequery=1');">
</script>
```

One advantage of this over using javascript in the `href` attribute is that it will display the link in the status bar, rather than a run script.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will do what you want it to?

https://jsfiddle.net/ewzvnbre/3/

`<a href="javascript:redirect()">
  Go to Link
</a>`

`<script>
function redirect(){
    window.location.replace('http://somehost.xyzas/section1/thing%2fwith%20slash/?qsp=1')
}
</script>`

Comment: location.href adds a new entry to the stack, so you can navigate to that location with the back button. I have to use replace because the link shouldn't add an extra element in browser history.